# Profile GAE application in local dev server with VisualVM

Tags: java, google-app-engine, visualvm

I have an app that consumes so much memory, I would like to profile it, but I'm unable to start the app and pass the argument -agentpath; after I add this argument it waits for the profiler to connect, and so the GAE application doesn't startup. I get this message

```
Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol version: 15)
```

I'm using maven to start up GAE application.
Sample command to start up:

```
java -agentpath:C:/visualvm_139/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/windows-amd64/profilerinterface.dll=C:\visualvm_139\profiler\lib,5140 -javaagent:C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-java-sdk\1.9.59\appengine-java-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.59\lib\agent\appengine-agent.jar -Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=5 -classpath C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-java-sdk\1.9.59\appengine-java-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.59\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain -p 8888 C:\Users\User\eclipse\workspace\App\
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be using;

-Xdebug
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y

which would block the app until a debug client is attached on port 8000.

Comment: I got a better result; the app waited until I attached on port 8000, and after that I got this message:  Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol version: 15), which is good, however when tried to start profiler it said "Profiled application started too soon"

Comment: Consider not adding the jvisualvm agent for a partial result

Comment: Explain more please

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble using VisualVM with App Engine, you can try another approach, such as using Stackdriver to monitor different aspects of your Java VM, such as memory usage.

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm) has all the useful information on how to set up a Stackdriver agent and use its monitoring functions to determine where the memory leaks come from.

Comment: This plugin is useful for JVM running on Compute Engine, not an App Engine application.

Comment: You may want to check this [tutorial](http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Configuring-VisualVM-to-connect-to-the-app-server) on how to connect to a JVM on a remote application server.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to profile startup of your application (from the description it looks like you don't), just start your application normally (without -agentpath). Start VisualVM, open your application and go to Profiler tab.
if you need to profile startup of your application use [Startup profiler](https://visualvm.github.io/startupprofiler.html). It will tell you, what you should do.